# Connect knime to clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse, knime

I have a bunch of information in knime, which I want to put in a database called knime in Clickhouse using node db connector, then I have a user named Alireza, no matter how hard I try to connect it to the database, I wanted help in Clickhouse I registered in knime)

When I add the user and password in the users.xml configuration file, clickhouse does not come up at all, the firewall is also turned off.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfX0U.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgAeG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2t2T.png)

My settings in the users.xml config file in Clickhouse : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go3Em.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.